# bundle failed for css with direct child combinator

Tags: css, bundle, visual-studio-2022, mudblazor

I'm using visual studio 2022.
Following the steps on https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-you-bundle-and-minify-the-css-and-js-files-in-blazor-applications

After creating bundleconfig.json and adding my css files references I compile the and visual studios shows **expected identifier, found '>'**.

```
div:has(> a:focus) {
    /* Some declarations */
}
```